# Calculation of Task completion date based on available hours

Tags: excel

I need to create a template in **MS Excel** that will calculate project completion date based on the available start date(s) for each task and number of hours assigned for each task. (Number of Work hours in a day = 8, Total number for Work Hours in a Week = 40)

For Example, if we have 4 Tasks:
TASKS     Start Date    Hours     Completion Date
Task 1    1/1/2015     4 hours    1/1/2015 
Task 2    1/1/2015     4 hours    1/1/2015
Task 3    1/2/2015     10 hours   1/3/2015
Task 4    1/3/2015     8 hours    1/4/2015

Logic
IF Task Hours < 8 Hours a Day 
THEN the Task Completion Date = Same as Task Start Date
ELSE Completion Date = next calendar Date (taking sum of all hours for that task + any preceding tasks in consideration)

IF Completion Date Falls on (Sat or Sun)
THEN assign completion date based on the calculation = Next available Work Day

Can anyone please help me with the solution(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
=WORKDAY(C2,D2/8)
```

assuming the commencement dates are in ColumnC, the hours (numbers only) are in ColumnD and the working week is Monday to Friday bdi.